# C# Convert IntPtr into int

Tags: c#, dynamic, int

I am dynamically calling Windows API. I found some code online that can do this, and I took a whole lot of interest to it. The idea itself is brilliant to say the least. However, I can't seem to make it work for my code. The parameters for the dynamic call are as of type `string`, `string` `int[]`, and I would like to use the API `GetThreadContext` with the parameters of `pInfo.hThred` and `ref ctx` (shown below).

**API Call**

```
GetThreadContext(pInfo.hThread, ref ctx);
```

The above code will make a call to the GetThreadContext API (given that it is declared in my project) - and works perfectly fine. The beauty of the dynamic call, however, is that no declaration is needed. So, my attempt at the dynamic call:

```
ctx = new CONTEXT {ContextFlags = 0x10007};
PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo;

CInvokeAPI.Invoke("kernel32","GetThreadContext",pInfo.hThread, ctx);
```

The issue here is that I haven't a clue as to how I can pass parameter ctx as type int given the fact that it is a struct.

**Please see below for additional code**

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct CONTEXT
    {
        public uint ContextFlags;
        unsafe fixed byte unused[160];
        public uint Ebx;
        public uint Edx;
        public uint Ecx;
        public uint Eax;
        unsafe fixed byte unused2[24];
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public int dwProcessId;
        public int dwThreadId;
    }
```

**Call API Dynamically Class**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

/* 
 * Title: CInvokeAPI.cs
 * Description: Call API by name implementation in purely managed C# (no 'unsafe' mess here).
 * 
 * Developed by: affixiate 
 * Comments: If you use this code, I require you to give me credits. 
 */

public static class CInvokeAPI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Generates a new, non-garbage collectable string in memory. Use this with Unicode "W" API.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="theString">A Unicode string.</param>
    /// <returns>Address of newly allocated string in memory. Remember to free it after use.</returns>
    public static int StringToPtrW(string theString)
    {
        return StringToPtr(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(theString));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates a new, non-garbage collectable string in memory. Use this with ANSI "A" API.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="theString">An ANSII string.</param>
    /// <returns>Address of newly allocated string in memory. Remember to free it after use.</returns>
    public static int StringToPtrA(string theString)
    {
        return StringToPtr(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(theString));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Internal method used to allocate memory.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="buf">A byte buffer.</param>
    /// <returns>Address of newly allocated memory. Remember to free it after use.</returns>
    private static int StringToPtr(byte[] buf)
    {
        return (int)GCHandle.Alloc(buf, GCHandleType.Pinned).AddrOfPinnedObject();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invokes the specified Windows API.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="libraryName">Name of the library.</param>
    /// <param name="functionName">Name of the function.</param>
    /// <param name="args">The arguments.</param>
    /// <returns>True if function succeeds, otherwise false.</returns>
    public static bool Invoke(string libraryName, string functionName, params int[] args)
    {
        /* Sanity checks. */
        IntPtr hLoadLibrary = LoadLibrary(libraryName);
        if (hLoadLibrary == IntPtr.Zero) return false;

        IntPtr hGetProcAddress = GetProcAddress(hLoadLibrary, functionName);
        if (hGetProcAddress == IntPtr.Zero) return false;

        // Allocates more than enough  memory for an stdcall and the parameters of a WinAPI function
        IntPtr hMemory = VirtualAlloc(IntPtr.Zero, 1024 * 1024, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, MEM_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
        if (hMemory == IntPtr.Zero)
            return false;

        IntPtr hMemoryItr = hMemory;

        // Prepends the stdcall header signature
        Marshal.Copy(new byte[] {0x55, 0x89, 0xE5}, 0, hMemoryItr, 0x3);
        hMemoryItr = (IntPtr)((int)hMemoryItr + 0x3);

        // Loop through the passed in arguments and place them on the stack in reverse order
        for (int i = (args.Length - 1); i >= 0; i--) 
        {
            Marshal.Copy(new byte[] {0x68}, 0, hMemoryItr, 0x1); 
            hMemoryItr = (IntPtr)((int)hMemoryItr + 0x1);
            Marshal.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(args[i]), 0, hMemoryItr, 0x4);
            hMemoryItr = (IntPtr)((int)hMemoryItr + 0x4);
        }

        Marshal.Copy(new byte[] {0xE8}, 0, hMemoryItr, 0x1);
        hMemoryItr = (IntPtr)((int)hMemoryItr + 0x1);
        Marshal.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)hGetProcAddress - (int)hMemoryItr - 0x4), 0, hMemoryItr, 0x4);
        hMemoryItr = (IntPtr)((int)hMemoryItr + 0x4);

        // Cleaning up the stack
        Marshal.Copy(new byte[] {0x5D, 0xC2, 0x4, 0x0 /* <= I made a LOL. */}, 0, hMemoryItr, 0x4);
        // Don't forget to increment if you are adding more ASM code here: hMemoryItr = (IntPtr)((int)hMemoryItr + 0x4);

        try
        {
            var executeAsm = (RunAsm) Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(hMemory, typeof (RunAsm));
            executeAsm();
        }
        catch { return false; }

        // Clean up the memory we allocated to do the dirty work
        VirtualFree(hMemory, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        return true;
    }

    // ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
    private const uint MEM_RELEASE = 0x8000;
    private const uint MEM_COMMIT = 0x1000;
    private const uint MEM_RESERVE = 0x2000;
    private const uint MEM_EXECUTE_READWRITE = 0x40;
    // ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming

    // My own sexy delegate:
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    private delegate void RunAsm();

    // WinAPI used:
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool VirtualFree(IntPtr lpAddress, UInt32 dwSize, uint dwFreeType);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr VirtualAlloc(IntPtr lpAddress, UInt32 dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string lpProcName);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the REAL parameters expected by myVoid on the unmanaged side ? is it really an HANDLE and a CONTEXT* ? If yes you will need to allocate some unmanaged memory for this an copy a CONTEXT instance inside it, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr.aspx if instead of a handle you need a PROCESS_INFORMATION* you need to do the same for this parameter.

Comment: Using 32 bit machine. Thank you though.

Answer (score 6):

Can you use the [IntPtr.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.toint32.aspx) method? That should work for the first parameter. Not sure about the struct conversion though.

Maybe take a look at [this post](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/162352) for ideas on how to convert the struct to an integer.

UPDATE:

There is no direct C# equivalent of VarPtr in C#, but I did find a manual referenced [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/clr/thread/2889deea-c21d-4242-b2e5-7211c84e4219) (along with an explanation of what it is doing... sounds similar to the explanation of VarPtr in [this post](http://www.thevbzone.com/secrets.htm#VarPtr)). This is an excerpt of the code. It may be useful for you:

```
public static int VarPtr(object e)
{
    GCHandle GC = GCHandle.Alloc(e, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    int gc = GC.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToInt32();
    GC.Free();
    return gc;
}
```

**NOTE: There are some potentials flaws to this function, as mentioned in this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/clr/thread/2889deea-c21d-4242-b2e5-7211c84e4219).**

Comment: Maybe for the first object being passed, but it will not work for the Context object.

Comment: @Evan: I added a link to a post that might get you started in the right direction (for the struct conversion).

Comment: @Evan: Maybe I can also be more help in the morning... very tired.

Comment: @Evan: Unfortunately there is no direct replacement for VarPtr in C#. I've updated my answer with a function that may be close enough for you needs, along with some links to explain things further.

Comment: I used Convert.ToInt32() on the first parameter, and VarPtr on the second parameter (Ctx) but still not luck. You may be on to something though..