# c# Convert struct to int

Tags: c#, struct, int

**Consider the following struct:**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct CONTEXT
{
public UINT ContextFlags;
unsafe fixed byte unused[160];
public uint Ebx;
public uint Edx;
public uint Ecx;
public uint Eax;
unsafe fixed byte unused2[24];
}
```

**And the following code:**

```
Context ctx = new Context{ ContextFlags = 0x10007 };
```

Now, I would like to convert this struct representative (ctx) into type int.

```
int x = (int)ctx;
```

The above method will not work, can someone think of the correct way for this conversion to take place?

Thank you,

Evan

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by converting a **structure** to **integer**? This doesn't make sense (your structure is much larger than 4 bytes). Do you want a pointer, maybe?

Comment: How do you want to convert almost 200-byte structure into `int`?.. I'm missing something probably...

Comment: Hm, what are you trying to do here?  int has 32 bits, and your struct has many many more.  So, do you need pointer or what?

Comment: I'm sorry - I am extremely new with this kind of stuff (just learning about pointers). I belive you are correct though, a pointer is what I'm looking for.

Comment: There is no reinterpret_cast in C#. You have to grab the actual property from inside the struct. Also C# doesn't have directly editable pointers.

Comment: OK, if you are new, please tell us what do you PLAN TO DO with the 'int' you want here?

Comment: **Why** do you want a pointer?

Comment: Not a problem. I found this really useful snippet which allows for API to be called dynamically on runtime. The function's last parameter looks like: params int[] parameters - and wants the API's parameters to be passed. The two parameters I have are pInfo.hthread (from Process_Info) and ctx (Context struct above).

Answer (score 6):

I'm suspicious that you plan on calling a Windows API method that uses [this structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679284%28VS.85%29.aspx). Perhaps even [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679362%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). In this case, the .NET marshaller will handle this for you.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetThreadContext(IntPtr thread, ref CONTEXT context);
```

Notice that you pass the structure using the `ref` keyword. The marshaller will take care of creating an unmanaged pointer to the structure and passing it on to the called method. It will also handle bring the pointer back as a structure should the method modify the structure's data.

Comment: Yes, this is the exact API that I am using ... Although when dynamically calling this API are you suggesting that I can use the ref keyword?

Comment: @Evan - On a side note, there's a [website](http://pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=GetThreadContext) that can show you some of the API signatures like the one above.

Comment: @Evan: Your function signature is probably wrong.  Please show us your code.

Comment: @Evan: hard to comment on that error without more code to look at. I would guess either a typo where your DLLImport resides or at the call site. Also, remove `unsafe fixed` from your two array declarations within the structure.

Comment: @Slaks I made this post a while ago, I think it died out but it has my full code in it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921983/c-convert-intptr-into-int

Comment: @Evan: Are you passing `ref ctx` to the `params int[]` in your `CInvokeAPI.Invoke` method from your other question? Just say no. Call the Windows API directly. As you are finding out, trying to dynamically call native methods is very, very painful and filled with gotchas.

Comment: @Matthew my EXACT call as of now is (cInvokeAPI.Invoke("kernel32", "GetThreadContext",pInfo.hThread, ctx);

Comment: @Evan: You are not using pointers. As for your `CInvokeAPI` method, I doubt you will be able to easily adapt that to this method, or any other Windows API method that takes a complex set of parameters. Notice that you are passing `hThread` and `ctx` to an `int[]`. You would have to change that to `object[]`, but you still need to pass `ctx` using `ref`, which you cannot do within a second method.